# Find limit of a sequence linked to a continued fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series

{2, 2/(1+2) ,2/(1+(2/(1+2))), ......} prove that the sequence converges to 1.
I construct the sequence in this way $x_1=2$ , and $x_{n+1}=\dfrac{2}{1+x_n}$. But can't show this. Please help me.

Comment: If a sequence converges then it satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Comment: Give a name $f(x):=2/(1+x)$. Do you recognize that you have to apply to $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ a "fixed point strategy" ?

Comment: Do you agree that, **if there is convergence**, it is towards a limit $L$ such that $L=\dfrac{2}{1+L}$ giving a quadratic equation whose roots are ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously:
$0\leq x_n\leq 2$

Introduce $y_n:\space0\leq y_{n+1}=\left ( x_{n+1}-1 \right )^2=\left(\frac{x_n-1}{1+x_n}\right)^2\leq y_n\leq1$

Since $y_n$ is bounded and monotonic, it converges, and hence so does $x_n$.